# How to get $\{1,4,7,10, 13...\}$ from $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

My question is pretty simple yet I'm confused. I have $i=\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ and I want to construct a formula to get $n=\{1,4,7,10, 13,...\}$.

Comment: Did you just change the whole question?

Comment: @MJD yes My calculations were wrong. I want to map the natural numbers to a sequence separated by 3 not 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just arithmetic sequence with difference $d=3$ and $a_1=1$, so $$ f(n) = 3n-2$$